# C# Encrypt string with public RSA-1280 hex key

Tags: c#, encryption, key, rsa, public

I've been trying to encrypt a password with a public RSA key that is sent to me by the server.

```
var csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider");
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1280, csp);
byte[] key = ByteUtils.HexToBytes(client.RSAKey);
RSA.ImportCspBlob(key);
byte[] encrypted = RSA.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password), true);
```

The hex key is provided in such format:

```
string key = "30819D300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818B0030818702818100C7BD672D8C634D443840AD809790852770D3A2E99F456D6516329E0205D0645C23FD001D4D070CEE368A20526FEB2402358C915D7E86102B1659AA8651C449C344599F72BE904B8E338E7002E9978453C5BBCCA51AC165AA265069E0EAB1411D11A2FFDD35E5A8296A6A2AF238945874E8206979B0A16E2E4260A161CAB5C905020111";
```

As the string is 320-bytes long in hex format, I assume the key is 160 bytes (RSA 1280)
Using this method, the provider keeps saying "Bad Version of provider.\r\n".
I've tried several methods, convert it to Base64, simply import it as ASCII / Unicode. Nothing worked so far.

EDIT: My HexToBytes function (which works afaik, it returns me correct 160-b array):

```
public static byte[] HexToBytes(string pValue)
        {
            // FIRST. Use StringBuilder.
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            // SECOND... USE STRINGBUILDER!... and LINQ.
            foreach (char c in pValue.Where(IsHexDigit).Select(Char.ToUpper))
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }

            // THIRD. If you have an odd number of characters, something is very wrong.
            string hexString = builder.ToString();
            if (hexString.Length % 2 == 1)
            {
                //throw new InvalidOperationException("There is an odd number of hexadecimal digits in this string.");
                // I will just add a zero to the end, who cares (0 padding)
                Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Debug, "Hexstring had an odd number of hexadecimal digits.");
                hexString += '0';
            }

            byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
            // FOURTH. Use the for-loop like a pro :D
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, j += 2)
            {
                string byteString = String.Concat(hexString[j], hexString[j + 1]);
                bytes[i] = HexToByte(byteString);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

Comment: What does your HexToBytes method look like? Is it possible there is an error in that code?

Comment: I'm quite sure it returns a byte array from the hex, thing is that it's not expecting that as a key for some odd reason.

Comment: `HexToBytes` looks wrong to me. It looks like you are reversing the order of the bytes. The whole use of the `StringBuilder` looks pointless and error-inducing.

Comment: His `HexToBytes` works, provided it is a valid length. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @Cedric I'd verify that you are receiving the key correctly, that you've specified the right key size, and that the registry values for your `CspParameters` arguments haven't been altered in some way.

Comment: I am not sure about the CspParameters (I saw this at some forum & tried it, no result anyway), I am sure that those bytes contain the RSA public key but basically can't seem to figure out in which format it's provided. There's nothing in my registry so the csp is obsolete?

Also, someone had thesame problem in 2006 but it has never been solved:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/519190f2-e0c2-4ce9-8c65-545a82de9a80/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your public key is not in the correct format. It is not a CSP blob. It is a DER encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure. You can find source code to parse it or you can write your own. [Here](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/dotnet/pempublic/pempublic.cs) is one example of such code.