# How to use c# to decrypt an MD5 hash that is encrypted using RSA1024

Tags: c#, md5, rsa, encryption

I trying to verify the integrity of a file at work and an having a hard time of it. I'm not very well versed with encryption and hashing, so bear with me.

I have some files that have an MD5 hash located at the end of them. I have written code to grab the bytes that I think are the hash and they seen to be uniformly 128 bytes long. In the file, just before the hash, is the keyword "RSA1024", which I have taken to mean the hash is encrypted using RSA 1024.

I have what I know is the RSA key in a file, and have read out the bytes (always 258 bytes long). I have seen many tutorials which use FromXmlString() to pull in the key, but this RSA key was not generated using the .net framework, and is not in an XML format.

I have written the following method to decrypt the hash data using the key, and it throws this error when executing ImportCspBlob() - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Version of provider.

Any ideas?

```
    public byte[] DecryptRSA(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] keyData)
    {
        CspParameters param = new CspParameters();
        param.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(param);

        rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(keyData);

        byte[] decryptedData = rsaProvider.Decrypt(encryptedData, false);

        return decryptedData;
    }
```

## Basic Algorithm

It may sound strange to want to *"decrypt an MD5 hash"*, and especially when one says that they want to *"decrypt it with a public key"*. But that is how digital signatures work. With RSA you can:

- **encrypt** with private key
- **decrypt** with the public key

[image]

The message digest is *encrypted* with the private key, and can then only be decrypted with the *public* key. That way you know that only the person with the private key could have signed the message.

Comment: Just so you know, you cannot "unhash" or "decrypt" a hash code. Hashing is a one way operation. That said, I believe your question is actually about decryption and the word hash is just misused! Just an fyi

Comment: To clarify - The file has been hashed using MD5, then the MD5 result was encrypted with RSA1024 and the result appended to the file?

Comment: You can't decrypt/dehash an MD5. The [MD5 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is **one-way.**

Comment: Any chance you are the same person as [this questioner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360193/c-encrypt-string-with-public-rsa-1280-hex-key/7367660#7367660)?

Comment: Sorry, Kevek. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to decrypt the Hash, which I understand cannot be done. I want to decrypt the result of encrypting the hash, which is what is stored at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your key is most likely not a CSP-type key (it is most likely DER encoded).  You can decrypt it using [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) with the DER key like this:

```
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(key);

byte[] rv = null; 
RsaEngine eng = new RsaEngine(); 
eng.Init(false, privateKey);
int size = eng.GetOutputBlockSize();
rv = eng.ProcessBlock(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
```

**EDIT:** to addressing GregS scenario that it may be a signature verify operation

If you are trying to verify a signature, you would need a certificate used to verify a message, the original message text, and the existing message signature to compare against.

What you do is pass in the original message text (minus the signature), the bytes of the message signature, and the path to the certificate you will use to verify the passed in signature.

Then, you will hash the original message and compare the result against the passed in signature.

Here is some code to illustrate:

```
private bool VerifySignature(string messageText, byte[] messageSignature, string certificatePath)
{
    // Load the certificate from a file
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath);

    // Get public key
    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

    // Next, hash the messageText
    SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageText);
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    // Verify the signature with the hash
    return csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), messageSignature);
}
```

Comment: Hopefully not. If it is a private key in that file then all is lost.

Comment: I took it to mean he has a key (in a seperate file than what he is checking), and then he takes the bytes from the file to be checked and tries to decrypt it using that key.  I am thinking his key is DER encoded.

Comment: I can't be certain but based on his description he appears to be trying to verify a signature.

Comment: Tried the above code, but no go.I get either a "unexpected end-of-contents marker" error, or if I remove the first two bytes that contain the EOT byte, I get the error "DER length more than 4 bytes: 27"

Comment: Just tried the code located at http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/dotnet/pempublic/pempublic.cs as well. But the key is not in these formats either.

Comment: @GregS - addressed your assumption, and now re-reading it, it looks like you may be right.

Answer (score -1):

MD5 is one-way hash. But you might check out hashing algorithm. There are some ways to break this hash, just do some research ;)

Comment: +1. MD5 is a one-way hash, it cannot be decrypted unless you use brute-force, or you check the hash against a list of known values.

Comment: Re-read the question. He wants the value of the encrypted hash (the MD5 value was encrypted - he wants it back).

Comment: Right, it was late for me. Shame on me.